Listen to sol receive transactions for desired wallet address
I've been trying to listen to all the transactions that my wallet receives but I was not able to... I'm using solana/web3.js with quickNode, I've tried using multiple methods such as getLogs, which unfortunately only works whenever transaction is sent from specific wallet and not received... I also tried using onAccountChange method, which works, but only for sol transactions and not for the spl tokens...
If any of you know any valid way to solve this problem, I'd be more than happy to hear. Thank you in advance...

You'll need to also do an onAccountChange for your SPL token accounts if you want to detect receiving transactions, since as you noticed, your wallet is not included in the transaction when receiving tokens.

What if I'm receiving something for the first time? How can I add it in advance?

If the account is created with the associated token account program, then your wallet address will be part of the transaction, so you can listen for transactions that reference your wallet and look for any instructions to the associated token account program. If it references a new account owned by your wallet, you can add it to the list. Or you can just maintain a list of possible associated token accounts for your wallet and listen for those, even if they don't exist.

Can you suggest any method or any way to do such thing? How do I listen to it, so I get notified? Thanks in advance.

I usually don't know what the address will be since those are airdrop tokens with unknown addresses. Would like to know if you have any solution idea without using intervals to check...
